# Configure jQuery event calendar (wdCalendar) to 24-hour time

Tags: jquery, calendar

A friend recommended [wdCalendar](http://www.web-delicious.com/jquery-plugins/#calendar) to me as an easy-to-use calendar/scheduling tool for my PHP site.  I was able to add it to my site fairly easily but am having trouble finding out how to configure it to be in 24-hour mode (I need 3:00 p.m. instead of 15:00).

Does anyone know if this is possible with this calendar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the calendar is not designed to support the 12-hour format but it surely is possible with a few modifications in the source code.

The source is fairly moderate in complexity and it's perfectly possible to make the calendar be in the 12-hour format (with a little coding effort, of course).

I have worked on the same already, so here's an assurance.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the function fomartTimeShow in jquery.calendar.js to match below:

```
    function fomartTimeShow(h) {
        if (h < 10 && h >= 00){
            return h + ":00 AM";
        }
        if (h >= 10 && h < 12) {
            return h + ":00 AM";
        }
        if (h === 12){
            return h + ":00 PM";
        }
        if (h > 12){
            return (h-12) + ":00 PM";
        } else {
            return h + ":00";
        }
    }
```